# Sketching Functions

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

> Sketch the region enclosed by $x+y^2=30$ and $x+y=0$. Decide whether to integrate with respect to $x$ or $y$. Then find the area of the region.

How do I start off sketching? Very first step?

I'm in Calc 2 and it's sad that I don't know what to do but I am trying to learn.

Comment: Unfortunately sticking numbers into a calculator doesn't work for my class.

Comment: How do I plot points is what I'm trying to do. Using a calculator is not permitted in my class.

Comment: "Pick a handful of x values, calculate the y values and draw the general shapes" this is what I don't know how to do.

Comment: I don't understand why we are choosing x values.

Comment: @Moo You can define a line with two points, what are you doing, you madman.

Comment: ok so for the parabola, we have those points now what do we do with the points exactly?

Comment: He's right tbh though I think he's said it in a bit of a confusing way. When you're plotting a curve, it's often easiest to take a few points as samples and then draw the line between them. In fact, this is often what your computer does. So what you can usually do is to turn your curve into some equation $y=f(x)$, then select a number of $x$ values, and for each $x$, find its corresponding $y$. Then plot each point by its $(x,y)$ co-ordinates and draw the curve between the points. But for a line, you only need to take $2$ points and if you take any more, you're just wasting your time.

Comment: so how do you know what 2 points will be your final points?

Comment: A line's gonna stay the same line regardless of which $2$ points you use to draw it with. But in practice, use $2$ that are kinda far apart so your drawing's more accurate.

Comment: Do you know what functions of the form $y = x$ and $y^2 = x$ look like? And do you know how they transform when you add or multiply values to the right hand side?

Comment: When you multiply values no, I know the forms yes.

Answer (score 2):

Can you sketch $y=30-x^2$? This is fairly standard highschool stuff. Once you do that, flip it over the line $y=x$ to interchange the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, to get $x=30-y^2$. That’s your first graph. The other one is easier, it’s $y=-x$ (you can also think of it as $x=-y$), still standard highschool stuff. With your two pictures, you are ready to go. You’ll need to know the points of intersection, those are where $x=30-y^2$ and $x=-y$, in other words where $30-y^2=-y$. Solve for $y$ by putting them all on one side of the equals sign, $0$ on the other side, and then factoring your quadratic in $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Try to identify the types of the functions you need to sketch by rewriting them in more familiar forms. For instance, you can write the first equation as $y^2=-(x-30)$. This is a parabola that has the same shape as $y^2 = x$. This latter function is a parabola with its axis of symmetry parallel to the $x$ axis, opening to the right, with its vertex at the origin. To understand what $y^2 = -(x-30)$ looks like, we need to reflect this parabola around the $y$ axis (so it will now open to the left; this is because of the negative sign in front). Then, we shift the parabola rightward by $30$ units. Thus, the curve is a parabola opening to the left, with its vertex at $(30, 0)$.

The second equation is clearly linear because it only involves single powers of $x$ and $y$. It can be rewritten as $y = -x$ which is a line with a $y$ intercept of $0$, and a slope $-1$.

Now you know the general shapes of each of the curves. To finish, you should determine where the curves intersect. This can be done by solving the system of equations using substitution. Knowing the general shapes of each curve, and knowing the points where they intersect should be enough to sketch the curves.

Answer (score 2):

You have some good online sketchers to help you to visualize the functions and compare it with your results when you are a little bit lost. For instance in the case of writing the functions in terms of $y=f(x)$ ([e.g in this page](https://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=sqrt(30-x)&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=-x&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=-17&x_max=17&y_min=-10.5&y_max=10.5&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525)) this is how it looks like:

In blue: $y=\sqrt{30-x}$

In red:  $y=-x$

And from that point you can continue to develop your solution to the problem.

[image]

And in terms of $x=f(y)$ ([link here](https://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=30-(x%5E2)&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=-x&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=-17&x_max=17&y_min=-10.5&y_max=10.5&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525)) it looks like this:

In blue: $x=30-y^2$

In red:  $x=-y$

[image]